# В строке 11 (arg = [args[i]+1...) возникает ошибка:"can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = [0.55, 0.25, 0.53, 0.45, 0.55]
# s[i] = s[i]–a∙s[i–1]

def pre_process(a):
    def _decorator(func):
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            arg = [args[i]+1 for i in range(len(args))]  # s[i] = s[i]–a∙s[i–1]
            return func(arg)
        return _wrapper
    return _decorator


@pre_process(a=0.93)
def plot_signal(s):
    for sample in s:
        print(sample)


plot_signal(s)
```

В строке 11 (arg = [args[i]+1...) возникает ошибка:"can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы передаете в `plot_signal()` список `s`, то в `args` внутри декоратора попадает следующее: `([0.55, 0.25, 0.53, 0.45, 0.55],)`, т.е. по сути `s` - это первый элемент из набора параметров `args`. Поэтому `args[0]+1` эквивалентно `[0.55, 0.25, 0.53, 0.45, 0.55] + 1`, на что и ругается интерпретатор.

Решения два:

`-` передавать `s` через "звездочку" (тогда нужно соответствующим образом поменять саму функцию): `plot_signal(*s)` 
`-` внутри декоратора выделить первый элемент (s), а потом отдельно `*args` и `**kwargs`:

```
def _wrapper(s, *args, **kwargs):
   s = [s[i]+1 for i in range(len(s))]
   return func(s, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Преобразовывать args в список не нужно, это уже кортеж, можно обращаться по индексу: `s = args[0]`

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, преобразовал к списку, т.к. для `tuple` нельзя сделать `args[0] = s`

Comment: Можно сделать так: `s, *other = args; ...; return func(s, *other, **kwargs)`

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, можно еще проще) изменил ответ